# Which Law of Large Numbers ensures the second equation in the picture is true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

There are several laws of large numbers, but in most versions I've seen there's the usual conclusion $1/n \sum^n_{t=1}u_t \rightarrow^p \mu$, for the usual condition of $E(u_t)=\mu$. However, in the next picture, I don't seem to be able to use the usual LLN.

[image]

Result (3.44) is $Var(\hat u_t^2)=E(\hat u_t^2)=(1-h_t)\sigma^2$, and it's also the result they refer to as 'in the previous exercise', and (3.46) is just the first equation, without the plims.

In this picture, if I were to use the usual LLN, I would say that $\hat \sigma^2$ would converge to $E(\hat u_t^2)=(1-h_t)\sigma^2$, but it depends on t...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The condition that $E(1/n \sum^n_{t=1}u_t)=\mu$ is certainly not sufficient to deduce any kind of convergence in probability.

Comment: @Did when you mean sufficient, do you mean it when considering also the other usual conditions that are stated with $E(u_t)=\mu$ ? or the condition just by itself?

Comment: "the usual conditions that are stated with E(ut)=μ" Please define.

Comment: @Did we could have u_t uncorrelated, and with finite second moments.

Comment: @Did I've just included a picture with an example I've found. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Not at all. The question clearly refers to other parts of the text.

Comment: @Did, I hope it's clearer now. I put the results they refer to.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between your two conditions (assuming i.i.d random variables).  If the expected value of a $X$ is $\mu$ then the expected value of $\bar{X}$ is $\mu$.  If the expected value of $\bar{X}$ is $\mu$ then the expected value of $X$ is $\mu$.

$$E(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{t})  = \mu \\
E(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{t}) = \frac{1}{n} E(\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{t}) \\
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}E(u_{t}) \\
= \frac{1}{n} n E(u_{t})\\
= E(u_{t}) = \mu $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I have some doubts about certain aspects. One of them is that the 2nd version of the theorem is usually used when we're not in the presence of identically distributed r.v. See the example I give in the question, in the 2nd paragraph. In this case, how would you answer?

Comment: Your two conditions are identical.  If you have $\mu = E(X)$ then you also have $\mu = E(\bar{X})$, at least for i.i.d. random variables.

Comment: Without the assumption of independence and identical distribution, the Law of Large Numbers does not come into play.  I do not understand your second paragraph: convergence to what?

Comment: There are versions of LLN. In some, you don't need iid assumption

Comment: There is a strong version and a weak version; both assume i.i.d. distribution.

Comment: That's not strictly true, the assumption can be relaxed.  But what do you think converges in your second paragraph?

Comment: Check my initial question. I've edited it